# omp_set_dynamic - how does the runtime determine the number of threads?

Tags: openmp

How does the OpenMP runtime determine the best number of threads when omp_set_dynamic is used?

e.g. Are some sort of timing mechanisms used or does the compiler give hints to the runtime of how large the task size is?

Comment: it's completely implementation specific.  most likely, you will end up using all available cores unless you using nested parallel blocks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that the OpenMP does determine the 'best' number of threads for an application, in any likely sense of the word 'best'.  As @aaa has commented, the runtime's behaviour when `omp_set_dynamic` is true is implementation specific.

I don't think that current Fortran/C/C++ compilers could provide information such as timings or task sizes to the runtime.

I believe that this function is available so that schedulers (and similar) can manage programs on machines, for throughput or similar.